# mkfs.gfs2 failing silently on centos7 cluster?

Tags: linux, cluster, lvm, pacemaker, gfs2

I'm building a test cluster using centos7 and pacemaker, with shared storage on GFS2 over clustered LVM.

I've set up a 2-node cluster, dlm and clvmd, both nodes can see the clustered logical volumes. Fencing is disabled for this cluster.

However, when I try to format the clustered logical volume as GFS2, the operation fails silently and no filesystem is created on it.

The output of `mkfs` (I created an ext4 filesystem on the logical volume previously to check if it was accessible):

```
[root@rsfe2 ~]# mkfs -t gfs2 -p lock_dlm -j 2 -t fecluster:cluster_lv_gfs /dev/cluster_vg_gfs/cluster_lv_gfs ; echo $?
It appears to contain an existing filesystem (ext4)
/dev/cluster_vg_gfs/cluster_lv_gfs is a symbolic link to /dev/dm-2
This will destroy any data on /dev/dm-2
Are you sure you want to proceed? [y/n]y
### a long time elapses...
1
```

Output of `pcs status`:

```
[root@rsfe1 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: fecluster
Last updated: Thu Nov  6 15:32:13 2014
Last change: Thu Nov  6 15:31:08 2014 via crmd on rsfe2.int
Stack: corosync
Current DC: rsfe1.int (1) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.10-32.el7_0.1-368c726
2 Nodes configured
4 Resources configured


Online: [ rsfe1.int rsfe2.int ]

Full list of resources:

 Clone Set: dlm-clone [dlm]
     Started: [ rsfe1.int rsfe2.int ]
 Clone Set: clvmd-clone [clvmd]
     Started: [ rsfe1.int rsfe2.int ]

PCSD Status:
  rsfe1.int: Online
  rsfe2.int: Online

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Versions:

```
[root@rsfe2 ~]# uname -a
Linux rsfe2 3.10.0-123.9.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 28 18:05:26 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@rsfe1 ~]# rpm -qa | egrep "pcs|pacemaker|corosync|clvmd|dlm|gfs"
corosync-2.3.3-2.el7.x86_64
pcs-0.9.115-32.el7.x86_64
dlm-4.0.2-3.el7.x86_64
pacemaker-libs-1.1.10-32.el7_0.1.x86_64
pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.10-32.el7_0.1.x86_64
pacemaker-cli-1.1.10-32.el7_0.1.x86_64
gfs2-utils-3.1.6-13.el7.x86_64
corosynclib-2.3.3-2.el7.x86_64
pacemaker-1.1.10-32.el7_0.1.x86_64
dlm-lib-4.0.2-3.el7.x86_64
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is your cluster name?

Comment: Cluster name: fecluster

Comment: try to create gfs2 fs in this way "mkfs -t gfs2 -p lock_nolock -j 2 -t fecluster:cluster_lv_gfs /dev/cluster_vg_gfs/cluster_lv_gfs" in one node, to see if you have problem with dlm

Comment: Behaviour persists with `-p lock_nolock`

Comment: you don't have error in your system logs?

Comment: nothing is written to /var/log/messages when the `mkfs` command is given. any other log location?

Comment: could you try to configure your fencing, this is because, gfs uses dlm and dlm depends on fencing

Comment: I have no viable fencing options. The cluster is running on Virtualbox on Windows, and vboxmanage doesn't work over cygwin ssh on windows, so I have no way to power off these hosts. Tried adding a "dummy" fence_apc device to no avail, issue is still present.